# How to make site resources accessible to all?

Tags: database, resources, migration, web-hosting

I migrated my wordpress site to a live server, but I've noticed that if I am not logged in the hosting provider site stylesheet and other resources won't load. I got the proof of this by a test whose link is this one - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQA4K.jpg -. I guess such resources are not accessible to non-logged-in users, how can I make it accessible for anonymous users too?

website: http://pendragonsbay.com

Comment: Why are you serving localhost URLs in production? How do you expect that to work?

Comment: Thank you for making me noticing that, how can I change it in order to use the live server URLs?

Comment: Change your code to use relative URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are simple common 404 errors. URL mistakes. It looks like you didn't update the resources URLs. Instead of http://localhost/myresourcename on such resource URLs within your theme files, you should replace with http://pendragonsbay.com/myresourcename.

Comment: Yes that was the error. If anyone was looking for more details about how to update URLs, google the sql scripts needed for URLs update or check step 7 of this guide http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/ plus make sure that home and siteurl are set as your site into wp_options.